# Osc communication between laptop and tablet in same WiFi network

Tags: android, processing, osc

I want to let my laptop and tablet communicate via OSC using OscP5 java library.

Tablet is android device and application is made on android studio.
Laptop is Windows 8.0 and application is running on Processing 2.2.1. Both uses same library OscP5.

WiFi network is very huge and strong in public government office. Both devices are obviously in same WiFi network named - Public WiFi Free. Both devices are using wireless(WiFi)

What I'm doing is very simple.
Send some integer from tablet to laptop through UDP unicast.

When I confirm IP address,
Laptop : 192.168.25.219
Tablet : 192.168.26.83

It's strange that they have different address which are 25 and 26.
I tried to reconnect on both device many times, but they always get same IP.

Problem is not port. I certainly confirmed that port is same(13000).
and laptop is just listening 13000 port and not sending anything.
Tablet is just sending to laptop IP on 13000 port.

I searched a bit and people are saying that if 1st, 2nd,and 3rd part of IP address is not same, OSC doesn't work. Is this the problem? and if so, Why? I'm kind of noob about network so please explain easily..

Comment: Yes, that can be the reason. But it depends on the network mask. Which values do they have? And what is OSC?

Comment: Subnet mask is 255.255.0.0. OSC is Open Sound Control(http://opensoundcontrol.org/introduction-osc)

Comment: Please one mask from laptop and one from tablet.

Comment: tablet subnetmask is 255.255.255.0 and laptop is 255.255.0.0. is this the problem? WiFi network is offered by government office so there is nothing I can do about network configuration.

Comment: The subnet mask of the laptop is the problem. It should have been equal to the one of the laptop.

Comment: You mean I have to change subnetmask of laptop? If I change it into 255.255.255.0 same as tablet, will it work? I'm so confused that I'm really noob on network.. Thank you very much anyway..

Comment: And I didn't set subnetmask that subnetmask is just given automatically when I connect to WiFi. Is it possible to change it manually?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo resulting in a nonsense sentence. The subnet mask of the tablet is the problem. But you cannot change that as the tablet gets it from the router where it is connected to.

Comment: I tried same thing at home with other WiFi which gives same subnetmask to both device as 255.255.255.0. But still not working.. I'm now suspicious of android side code... Thank you anyway..

Comment: `with other WiFi` One router or different routers? If laptop and tablet connect to the same router than probably your android code is not ok. Or the firewall is preventing connection.

Comment: My android code was problem. Also I couldnt think about firewall... stupid... after I turn it off, it works fine with other android code. Thank you so much @greenapps

Answer (score 0):

Problem was firewall...

Anyone who came to this post must confirm whether firewall is blocking your port or not. There are 2 possibility that firewall is blocking your port on router level or your OS level.

The first case, you have to access administrator setting page of your router and enable VPN(Virtual Private Network) pass-through or open port.
The last case(mostly in Windows because firewall is option in OS X), you simply go to settings and disable Home network level firewall, or you can add exception for you port.

I hope someone will not have hard time like me because of firewall.